# Transpose data from CSV

Tags: excel, database, google-sheets, transpose, flatten

I have an CSV with this pattern:

```
Column 1, Column 2, Column 3,  
NAME 1, APP1, APP2 
NAME 2, APP2 
NAME 3, APP1, APP3
```

I would like to transpose this data and get this result

```
Column 1, Column 2, Column 3,  
NAME 1, APP1
NAME 1, APP2 
NAME 2, APP2 
NAME 3, APP1
NAME 3, APP3
```

I would like to do it on excel or google sheets.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A2:A&"×"&B2:C), "×"), "where Col2 is not null", ))
```